# Can Databricks Auto loader infer partitions?

Tags: databricks, databricks-autoloader

By default, when you're using Hive partitions directory structure,the auto loader option `cloudFiles.partitionColumns` add these columns automatically to your schema (using schema inference).

This is the code:

```
checkpoint_path = "s3://dev-bucket/_checkpoint/dev_table"
(
    spark
    .readStream
    .format("cloudFiles")
    .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
    .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_path)
    .load("s3://autoloader-source/json-data")
    .writeStream
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)
    .trigger(availableNow=True)
    .toTable("dev_catalog.dev_database.dev_table")
)
```

But can we have an option to also create partitionq to the target table like you can do with a simple `CREATE TABLE` ? (E.g. if you have such classical structure /year=xxxx/month=xxx/day=xx)

Comment: Could you provide the code for the write to the target table?

Comment: Nothing more than the code from the Databricks documentation 

```checkpoint_path = "s3://dev-bucket/_checkpoint/dev_table"

(spark.readStream
  .format("cloudFiles")
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_path)
  .load("s3://autoloader-source/json-data")
  .writeStream
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)
  .trigger(availableNow=True)
  .toTable("dev_catalog.dev_database.dev_table"))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [.partitionBy()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.ss/api/pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.partitionBy.html#pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.partitionBy) function.

```
checkpoint_path = "s3://dev-bucket/_checkpoint/dev_table"
(
    spark
    .readStream
    .format("cloudFiles")
    .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
    .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_path)
    .load("s3://autoloader-source/json-data")
    .writeStream
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)
    .partitionBy("col1", "col2")
    .trigger(availableNow=True)
    .toTable("dev_catalog.dev_database.dev_table")
)
```